# Using Android Eclipse Calendar without account

Tags: android, eclipse, calendar, account

I have a question.

I am working with an android Calendar (just the default one from the XML graphic editor). I would like to be able to add Events but Eclipse keeps nagging me about needing to sync with an account. However once I created (and synced!) this account (just my personal one) it still doesn't work. I did some research but couldn't find the answer/solution anywhere online. I followed several calendar tutorials but this kept coming up.

My question is: would it be possible to create an event in the calendar without using a google account? Eventually I would even like to generate events automatically if possible, but for now just adding an event by clicking a button would make me very happy!

My XML files:

```
<RelativeLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.deitel.welcome.CalendarActivity" >

<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Add Event" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Java code:

```
package com.deitel.welcome;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Calendars;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class CalendarActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            //add event to calendar
            addCalendarEvent();
        }

    });

}

public void addCalendarEvent(){

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();     
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
    intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
    intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
    intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
    intent.putExtra("title", "Test Event");
    intent.putExtra("description", "This is a sample description");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I also added in the Manifest that users have the permisson to write and read events by adding these two lines:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
```

So please... Does anyone know if

1) it is possible to add events to a calendar without having to sync a google account?
2) how I can implement it in my code?

Thank you so much for reading and taking time to answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies not in your use of the CalendarView, but in the intent you use to add the event.  That intent is specifically used to add events to the Android calendar, which is backed by a google account.  In addition, the permissions you've added are for accessing the devices calendar.

Yes, it is possible to create your own calendar were the data is local to you app, but it won't be easy.  You'll have to create the layouts for adding and displaying the events as well as saving the data either in files, or some database

Comment: Hmm okay thanks for your answer. Do you maybe know of a tutorial of some kind that might help me?

Comment: Sorry, I know of no tutorials, but I did find an open source off-line calendar program: https://github.com/dschuermann/offline-calendar.  You may find looking the source helpful.